# Problems converting image to black and white in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, ubuntu

Im having problems with my a program. I have been trying to google the problems but cant seem to find annything i can use. I am quite new to C so trying to learn all i can.

When i try to run it with `./imgconvert.c` i get the following errors:

```
 ./imgconvert.c: line 6: struct: command not found
 ./imgconvert.c: line 7: uint8_t: command not found
 ./imgconvert.c: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
 ./imgconvert.c: line 8: `};'
```

I have tried to compile the program to somthing like `myProgram.o` with:
`gcc -c imgconvert.c -o myProgram.o` and then `./myProgram`. But I get a permission error, if I fix that with chmod then I get this error:

```
bash: ./myProgram.o: cannot execute binary file
```

I dont know what to do?

Code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pixel {
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
};

static uint8_t *load_image(char *filename, int *sizex, int *sizey)
{
    uint8_t *image;
    char buf[512];
    char *bufptr;
    int ret;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    bufptr = fgets(buf, 512, fp);
    ret = fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n", sizex, sizey);
    bufptr = fgets(buf, 512, fp);

    image = malloc(*sizex * *sizey * 4);

    int i;
    uint8_t *ptr = image;
    for (i=0; i<*sizex * *sizey; ++i) {
        ret = fread(ptr, 1, 3, fp);
        ptr += 4;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return image;
}

static int save_image(const char *filename, uint8_t *image, int sizex, int sizey)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", sizex, sizey);

    int i;
    uint8_t *ptr = image;
    for (i=0; i<sizex * sizey; ++i) {
        fwrite(ptr, 1, 3, fp);
        ptr += 4;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}

void convert_grayscale(uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output, int sizex, int sizey)
{
    // Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizex * sizey; ++i)
        {
            struct pixel *pin = (struct pixel*) &input[i*4];
            struct pixel *pout = (struct pixel*) &output[i*4];

            float luma = 0.299 * pin->r + 0.587 * pin->g + 0.114 * pin->b;

            if (luma > 255)
                luma = 255;

            uint8_t intluma = (int) luma;

            pout->r = intluma;
            pout->g = intluma;
            pout->b = intluma;
            pout->a = 255;
        }

}

int main()
{
    uint8_t *inputimg, *outputimg;
    int sizex, sizey;

    inputimg = load_image("image.ppm", &sizex, &sizey);

    outputimg = malloc(sizex * sizey * 4);

    convert_grayscale(inputimg, outputimg, sizex, sizey);

    save_image("output.ppm", outputimg, sizex, sizey);
}
```

Comment: Grayscale != Black and white.  If you want B&W you want to a binarization filter which has a middle value that everything > n becomes a 1 and everything < n becomes zero.

Comment: In future, please put your code inline in the question; don't link to an external site.  We want the question to still make sense years from now, and "pastebin" type sites often delete things after a little while.

Answer (score 2):

Your *immediate* problem is that C programs must be compiled *and linked*.  Your GCC invocation uses the `-c` option, which tells it to only do the "compile" part.  Try instead

```
gcc -g -Wall imgconvert.c -o imgconvert
```

and then

```
./imgconvert
```

I added some new options, `-g` which means generate debugging information, and `-Wall` which means enable all warnings that really ought to be on by default but aren't.  I haven't looked at your code in detail, but it is *very likely* that you will get some "warning:" messages from the first command, which you should fix.

With the `-c` option, what you get is an "object" file (that's what the ".o" stands for) which is only useful as input to a subsequent link operation.  You'll want that when you start writing programs that are larger than can sensibly fit in one file.

And by the way, the errors you got when you tried to execute the C source code directly are because, thanks to ancient defaults preserved for backward compatibility, the shell tries to execute anything that isn't recognizable as a compiled executable (`\177ELF` at the beginning of the file) or properly-labeled interpreted script (`#! /path/to/interpreter` at the beginning of the file) as if it were a shell script.

Comment: This worked. I got an black and white image as planned. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `-c` to gcc only compiles the source file into an object file. You should omit it (as well as the ".o" suffix) when building the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You have the compile the program into an executable. Assuming it consists of only one file (`imgconvert.c`):

```
cc -o imgconvert imgconvert.c
```

Then you can run it:

```
./imgconvert
```